# Google Drive Api: receive push notifications on local environment

Tags: google-drive-api, localhost

I'm interested in receive changes notifications form google drive api.

In order to receive notifications you have to make an http request with the addess where notifications have to be received:

Example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a77", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://somedomain.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myChangesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

As you can see, I'm setting that google sends push notifications at `"https://somedomain.com/notifications"`.

Nevertheless, I'm on a local/development behavior environment and I would need to receive notifications on my local ip.

Is there any alternative.

Comment: How did you overcome this? I am currently stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), or [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel). To install them just follow their links.

They allow you to expose your `localhost` to the world for testing.

Ngrok example: `ngrok http <local-server-port>`

Localtunnel example: `lt --port <local-server-port>`

Comment: Tried this. Does not work as Google requires Domain Verification. I am really stuck here

Answer (score 0):

You could use [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) and set up a subdomain that is stable to your development and use it to verify the domain in google verification.

There is a command that sets your subdomain statically

`lt --port 8000 --subdomain {subdomain name here}`

and then I verified the domain in Google through downloading a verification file (More on this during verification).

You should not get a domain and use it during development just to verify with google or any other service. It will only increase complexity